# Bad image on a 32" FullHD TV

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I bought a 32" Full HD TV max res: 1920x1080 works really well I have it connected to my notebook via mini HDMI cable.

It's super for watching TV shows or playing games but for working it's just horrible. Like text is not as sharp also it's much bigger than on laptops screen.

For instance I will have 9px font very sharp and clear on my laptop screen but when dragged to  my TV it seems as if it enlarged into 12px font also it's not that sharp. However I did not have this problem on a 24" Full HD monitor I didn't see the font difference or difference in sharpness.

I tried input settings from console to pc to cinema etc. Nothing really helps that much as well as sharpness and AA settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your 32" TV has ~69 pixels per inch. A 100 pixel object on the screen will be **1.45 inches** in size.

Your 24" screen has ~91 pixels per inch. A 100 pixels object on the screen will be **1.10 inches** in size.

Assuming your laptop has a 1280x800 pixel 15" screen, that's ~100 pixels per inch and that same object will be **1 inch** in size.

Most screens are between 90 and 110 pixels per inch today, with a clear trend towards higher PPI (often with the operating system increasing the pixel size of things to keep the size effectively the same, only sharper). Assuming your laptop screen is a bit nearer to your eyes than your 24" screen, the pixels appear to be roughly the same size to you.

But as you can see, the TV's are much larger. Assuming no greater viewing distance, you'll be more easily able to discern single pixels, as well as the strategies computers use to get rid of visual artifacts (aliasing).

TV screens are not designed for a typical computer viewing distance of ~20 inches or so. That's what e.g. the more expensive 2560x1440/27" or2560x1600/30" screens are for.

---

Of course, you may be able to configure your computer to reduce the size of objects (text etc.) on your TV screen to match the physical size of your other screens. However, this will not add more detail, making text of smaller sizes very difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks. The 2560x1440/27" screens are still bit to expansive for me I have been looking into a 27" FullHD monitor instead of TV. I use it for programming work and 32" FullHD up close is just very bad.

Comment: @kellax If you're comfortable reading text without eye strain in default size on the 24" Full HD screen, the 27" Full HD screen will not provide any advantage (other than being able to move it further away and still read text, etc.).